# Search files in a Sharepoint 2010 document set programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, caml

I'm on Sharepoint 2010 and I want to check if a file exists in a documentSet, how can i do that (with CAML if possible)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's a post by Isha Attlee that should do what you're looking for:

http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.com/2010/09/programmatically-get-document-set-for.html

An excerpt follows:

```
public bool IsDocumentSetItem(SPListItem itemToCheck)
{

bool documentSetItem = false;

if (itemToCheck.File != null)
{
DocumentSet documentSet;

documentSet = DocumentSet.GetDocumentSet(itemToCheck.File.ParentFolder);

if (null != documentSet)
{
documentSetItem = true;
}
}
return documentSetItem;
}
```